# Moodle: Auto-assignment of roles with LDAP

Tags: ldap, moodle

I am looking for the way to automatically assign users with different roles across LDAP.

I have found from this document (http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/LDAP_enrolment) that we could enroll users to courses and assign them with `teacher` and `student` roles.
But I wonder how it should be done if I want to assign other administrative roles through LDAP?
(I have found a few `User role assignment from LDAP` plugins as well, but I haven't tested them out yet.)

So I would like to know if that is achievable through Moodle's built-in features. Or I would have to install extensions or plugins? Or I would have to write some codes myself?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a quick look at the settings for LDAP enrolment and it looks like you can already map the system roles.

On your site go to

```
/admin/settings.php?section=enrolsettingsldap
```

There is a section for Role Mapping.